# Send the text to email from .txt file

Tags: python, email

Is there any way to send the text from text file(.txt) to email. i successful sent the attachment text file to email but i want to send only text instead of the whole file. Retrieve the text from the .txt file and send them.

Here is the code that i sent the email attachment

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import os.path

email = 'assassin@gmail.com' # Your email
password = '123abc' # Your email account password
send_to_email = 'james12@gmail.com' # Who you are sending the message to
subject = 'subject' # The subject line
message = 'ok' # The message in the email
file_location = r'C:\Users\hp\Downloads\SimpleCoin-master\SimpleCoin-master\simpleCoin\output.txt'

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email
msg['To'] = send_to_email
msg['Subject'] = subject

 # Attach the message to the MIMEMultipart object
msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

# Setup the attachment
filename = os.path.basename(file_location)
attachment = open(file_location, "rb")
part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload(attachment.read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

# Attach the attachment to the MIMEMultipart object
msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(email, password)
text = msg.as_string() # You now need to convert the MIMEMultipart object to a string to send
server.sendmail(email, send_to_email, text)
server.quit()
```

I just want to send text in email's body not the whole file attachment

Comment: What did you already try? What concrete issues are you facing?
Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i tried to send the attachment file and it successfully did as i expected but now i only want to send the text

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Shared @ChristianBaumann

Comment: Instead of sending the whole file, you can import the file and add the text to the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the following code:

```py
import smtplib
import os.path

email = 'assassin@gmail.com' # Your email
password = '123abc' # Your email account password
send_to_email = 'james12@gmail.com' # Who you are sending the message to
subject = 'subject' # The subject line

file_location = # File location here

with open(file_location) as f:
    message = f.read()

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(email, password)
text = "Subject: {}\n\n{}".format(subject , message)
server.sendmail(email, send_to_email, text)
server.quit()
```